# Delete the rows in data frame which have a special conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big data frame, I only provide three rows of that.

I want to delete some rows with special conditions. I want to move with window size 3 across the rows, and if a row has **more than 2** consecutive window size (sequence) exactly same as each other. I will delete that row.

The sequence which we consider that is repeated or not, is the column1, column2, column3.

For example, in the provided dataframe:

**row 1:** 1, 0, 1 repeat 3 times at first, and then repeat 2 times again. so, since we have three consecutive times for that, this row should be deleted.

**row 2:**  2, 6, 4 repeated 4 times consecutively at the last rows. Then we delete this row also.

**row3:** does not have any repetitive sequence, then we keep that row.
So, the desired output will be only row 3.

Here is the dataframe which I have:

```
   val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6  val7  val8  val9  val10  val11  val12  val13  val14  val15  val16  val17  val18
0     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     1      1      2      1      1      0      1      1      0      1
1     2     6     4     2     2     2     2     7     2      2      6      4      2      6      4      2      6      4
2     3     1     3     4     3     3     7     1     5      4      3      3      3      3      3      3      3      3
```

And here is the desired output (and also a list which shows maximum number of consecutive seaunce):

dataframe:

[image]

list:

```
L= [3, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

creat data frame:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['val1'] = [1,2, 3]
df['val2'] = [0,6, 1]
df['val3'] = [1,4, 3]

df['val4'] = [1,2, 4]
df['val5'] = [0,2, 3]
df['val6'] = [1,2, 3]

df['val7'] = [1,2, 7]
df['val8'] = [0,7, 1]
df['val9'] = [1,2, 5]

df['val10'] = [1,2, 4]
df['val11'] = [2,6, 3]
df['val12'] = [1,4, 3]

df['val13'] = [1,2, 3]
df['val14'] = [0,6, 3]
df['val15'] = [1,4, 3]

df['val16'] = [1,2, 3]
df['val17'] = [0,6, 3]
df['val18'] = [1,4, 3]
```

```py
>>> df
```

|  | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | val6 | val7 | val8 | val9 | val10 | val11 | val12 | val13 | val14 | val15 | val16 | val17 | val18 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 7 | 2 | 2 | 6 | 4 | 2 | 6 | 4 | 2 | 6 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 7 | 1 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |

code:

```py
index_of_drop = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    subset = []
    # give subset with size 3 across the rows -> val1-val3, val4-val6 &...
    for j in range(0, (len(list(row)) - 2), 3):
        subset.append(list(row)[j:j+3])
    # give each subset and count it in row
    for z in subset:
        if(subset.count(z) > 2):
            index_of_drop.append(i)
            break
        else:
            pass

df.drop(index=index_of_drop, inplace=True)
```

after this code :

```py
>>> df
```

|  | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | val6 | val7 | val8 | val9 | val10 | val11 | val12 | val13 | val14 | val15 | val16 | val17 | val18 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 7 | 1 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |